# Keeping trailing zero's when transferring from excel to word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, zero

I have this VBA code, where i pull data from word to Excel and then i transfer other data the other way around.

I have this code:
Call findAndReplace(Replace(Round(vbaSheet.Cells(i, "U").Value, 2), ",", "."), "Freight:", 3)

And this code for example takes a number like this from excel "155,40" and returns it to word as this "155.4".

This problem only occurs when there's a zero at the end of the decimals. But i want the number to be transferred as "155.40".
What can i add to t

[The returned number in word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Pb5.png)
[The number from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av8SE.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Format(findAndReplace(...),"0.00")
```

Or

```
vbaSheet.Cells(i, "U").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

is exactly what you need. Format takes the value and it forces it to return two digits after the comma.

Simply select tha cell and run this:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
End Sub
```

Then make it work in your loop.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: It gives me a compile error: Expected Function or variable.

Comment: @Madter - add the following after your line - `vbaSheet.Cells(i, "U") = Format(vbaSheet.Cells(i, "U"),"0.00")`

Comment: Now it returns the number without any decimals. I've put it underneath the line i already put up here

Comment: @Madter - `vbaSheet.Cells(i, "U").NumberFormat = "0.00"`

Comment: Still the same. Returns the number without any decimals

Comment: @Madter - that is strange. What happens if you select the number and run `Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"` in the immediate window?

Comment: It returns the number with a lot of these "---------------------------------"

Comment: @Madter - take a look at the edited answer. If it does not work, update your question with a screenshot.

Comment: It still returns it without decimals. I have attached two screenshots. Tell me if you need more screenshots

Comment: @Madter - I start to see your point. You should try to go through a `string` and simply write the string to Word. It could be better, if you put a bit more code.

Comment: @Vitayata - The problem is that all of the code works and everything. The only problem is when there are decimals with 0, then it doesn't transfer the zeros (as in the picture). I've attached a screenshot of some of the code, maybe i didn't understand you the first time. but could you tell med where you want me to put those codes you gave me?

Comment: @Madter - save the decimals as strings. Before saving them, format them as in the answer. Then write the strings to Word.